# String contents are same but equals method returns false

Tags: java, stringescapeutils

I am using StringEscapeUtils to escape and unescape html. I have following code

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class EscapeUtils {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String string = "    4-Spaces    ,\"Double Quote\", 'Single Quote', \\Back-Slash\\, /Forward Slash/ ";

        String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(string);
        String myEscaped = escapeHtml(string);

        String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(escaped);
        String myUnescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(myEscaped);

        System.out.println("Real String: " + string);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Escaped String: " + escaped);
        System.out.println("My Escaped String: " + myEscaped);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Unescaped String: " + unescaped);
        System.out.println("My Unescaped String: " + myUnescaped);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Comparison:");
        System.out.println("Real String == Unescaped String: " + string.equals(unescaped));
        System.out.println("Real String == My Unescaped String: " + string.equals(myUnescaped));
        System.out.println("Unescaped String == My Unescaped String: " + unescaped.equals(myUnescaped));

    }

    public static String escapeHtml(String s) {
        String escaped = "";
        if(null != s) {
            escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll(" ","&nbsp;");
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll("'","&#39;");
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll("\\\\","&#92;");
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll("/","&#47;");
        }
        return escaped;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Real String:     4-Spaces    ,"Double Quote", 'Single Quote', \Back-Slash\, /Forward Slash/ 

Escaped String:     4-Spaces    ,&quot;Double Quote&quot;, 'Single Quote', \Back-Slash\, /Forward Slash/ 
My Escaped String: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4-Spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;,&quot;Double&nbsp;Quote&quot;,&nbsp;&#39;Single&nbsp;Quote&#39;,&nbsp;&#92;Back-Slash&#92;,&nbsp;&#47;Forward&nbsp;Slash&#47;&nbsp;

Unescaped String:     4-Spaces    ,"Double Quote", 'Single Quote', \Back-Slash\, /Forward Slash/ 
My Unescaped String:     4-Spaces    ,"Double Quote", 'Single Quote', \Back-Slash\, /Forward Slash/ 

Comparison:
Real String == Unescaped String: true
Real String == My Unescaped String: false
Unescaped String == My Unescaped String: false
```

I `escaped` the real `string` and then `unescaped` it. but `myEsceped` is first escaped with same process, and then some more html characters are replaced with their html codes. `myUnescaped` is actually unescape of `myEscaped` which has same contents as that of real string.

Output shows that real `string`, `unescaped`, and `myUnescaped` contents are same. But, as in Comparison section, `myUnescaped` is not equal to `string` and `unescaped`.

I don't understand it yet what is actually happening here. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: oh my head is spinning

Comment: can you please debug and check the character array of string to verify and please share that

Comment: I don't see the line `Unescaped String == My Unescaped String:` in your code. Can you add the part of your program where this comparison is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This due to while escaping HTML, you are replacing `' '` with `&nbsp;`

```
public static String escapeHtml(String s) {
        String escaped = "";
        if(null != s) {
            escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll(" ","&nbsp;"); // HERE
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll("'","&#39;");
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll("\\\\","&#92;");
            escaped = escaped.replaceAll("/","&#47;");
        }
        return escaped;
    }
```

While [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) does not escape `' '`, below is the example on their site:

```
"bread" & "butter"
```

becomes

```
&quot;bread&quot; &amp; &quot;butter&quot;
```

**Which means `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` preserves spaces**

If from `escapeHtml` you remove `escaped = escaped.replaceAll(" ","&nbsp;");`, `unescaped` and `myUnescaped` match !

Answer (score 1):

After [Apurv Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208430/1307229), I have analyzed bytes array of strings.

```
String:        32,  32,  32,  32,  52,  45,  83, 112,  97,  99, 101, 115,  32,  32,  32,  32,  44,  34,  68, 111, 117,  98, 108, 101,  32,  81, 117, 111, 116, 101,  34,  44,  32,  39,  83, 105, 110, 103, 108, 101,  32,  81, 117, 111, 116, 101,  39,  44,  32,  92,  66,  97,  99, 107,  45,  83, 108,  97, 115, 104,  92,  44,  32,  47,  70, 111, 114, 119,  97, 114, 100,  32,  83, 108,  97, 115, 104,  47,  32
unescaped :    32,  32,  32,  32,  52,  45,  83, 112,  97,  99, 101, 115,  32,  32,  32,  32,  44,  34,  68, 111, 117,  98, 108, 101,  32,  81, 117, 111, 116, 101,  34,  44,  32,  39,  83, 105, 110, 103, 108, 101,  32,  81, 117, 111, 116, 101,  39,  44,  32,  92,  66,  97,  99, 107,  45,  83, 108,  97, 115, 104,  92,  44,  32,  47,  70, 111, 114, 119,  97, 114, 100,  32,  83, 108,  97, 115, 104,  47,  32
myUnescaped:  -96, -96, -96, -96,  52,  45,  83, 112,  97,  99, 101, 115, -96, -96, -96, -96,  44,  34,  68, 111, 117,  98, 108, 101, -96,  81, 117, 111, 116, 101,  34,  44, -96,  39,  83, 105, 110, 103, 108, 101, -96,  81, 117, 111, 116, 101,  39,  44, -96,  92,  66,  97,  99, 107,  45,  83, 108,  97, 115, 104,  92,  44, -96,  47,  70, 111, 114, 119,  97, 114, 100, -96,  83, 108,  97, 115, 104,  47, -96
```

I seems in `myUnescaped`, spaces has converted to ascii `-96` instead of `32`.

So I wrote an `unescapeHtml` method as below. This method first replaces `&nbsp` with a space and then use `StringEscapeUtils` to unescape html.

```
public static String unescapeHtml(String s) {
    String unescaped = "";
    if(null != s) {
        unescaped = s.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
        unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(unescaped);
    }
    return unescaped;
}
```

Then I got `myUnescaped` using following code.

```
String myUnescaped = unescapeHtml(myEscaped);
```

This gave me `myUnescaped` string equal to `string` and `unescaped`.

**ALTERNATIVELY** I replaced `&nbsp;` with `&#32;`. This does not require me to write `unescapeHtml` mehod. Updated `escapeHtml` method's code is given below.

```
public static String escapeHtml(String s) {
    String escaped = "";
    if(null != s) {
        escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(s);
        escaped = escaped.replaceAll(" ","&#32;");    //updated line 
        escaped = escaped.replaceAll("'","&#39;");
        escaped = escaped.replaceAll("\\\\","&#92;");
        escaped = escaped.replaceAll("/","&#47;");
    }
    return escaped;
}
```