# Javascript/jQuery Fail to Append html to body

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, uiwebview, android-webview

I'm working on an `android/ios` app. i need some sort of infinit scroll, so when user scroll and reaching the end of the page new content will load for him.

In the native code i store the new content in an string and then append it to the page with `javascript/jquery`.

for android:

```
String js = "javascript:(function() { document.body.innerHTML += '" + newContent + "';}())";
loadUrl(js);
```

so far so good, **BUT** if my `newContent` contains a set of *specific char* this code will **fail** and nothing append.

I discovered this char so far: `'`  `\n`  `&laquo;`  `&raquo;`  `&nbsp;`

If i replace this chars in the `newContent` then the code works fine and new content will append to body.

The *problem* is every time i think it's over and i find all illigal char a new char cause my code to fail.

I also tried to parse my `string` to `html` then add it, but it fails also.

```
js = "javascript:(function(){var html = $.parseHTML( '"+newContent+"' ); $(\"body\").append(html);}())";
loadUrl(js);
```

**so** is there any general way to get ride of this illegal chars?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao where?

Answer (score 1):

Your text contains unescaped special characters which causes error.
Try escaping the text with [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)

**Edit:**
It might be though that the javascript already fails because of the special characters, then you would have to escape the string with Java already. Try to google for "java escape string for javascript" and you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: tnx alot, i will try it.

Comment: I tried `String results = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(str);` and i give me something like this: `<p>\u064A\u0648\u0645 \u0643\u0627\u0645\u0644. 3 \u0640 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0635\u0631</p>`, it sometimes works and sometimes not !! whats the problem?

Comment: I still need to replace `&laquo;`  `&raquo; ` `&nbsp;`, how to get rid of these?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207625/string-contents-are-same-but-equals-method-returns-false &nbsp; is html code already, probably you have to unescape that back, I am not sure. You have to try it out: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML(str).

Comment: I tried `body = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(body); body = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(body);` But it still fail on some string.
like body of this page: http://pastebin.com/CMNDsgt5

Comment: Well, I'm sorry got no other idea.